# Disaster Recovery Ubuntu Server with Bacula

Tags: ubuntu, server, bacula

I want to setup a way using bacula, to complete restore a recovered ubuntu server system + ubuntu server LTS on a new machine.

My Workflow:

1. Installation of the latest Ubuntu Server LTS on my machine.
2. Restoring the saved fileset via bacula director from remote machine.

The fileset I saved from the machine looks like:

```
FileSet {
        Name = "developmentserver"
        Include {
                Options {
                        signature = MD5
                }
                File = "/"
                File = "/home"
                File = "/var"
                File = "/etc"
        }
        Exclude {
                File = "/dev"
                File = "/proc"
                File = "/sys"
                File = "/mnt"
                File = "/media"
                File = "/tmp"
                File = "/var/cache/apt"
        }
}
```

That configuarion wouldn't work, I get a lot of errors when restoring on the new machine. They look like this:

```
Error: create_file.c:223 Could not create /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data/base/16385/17972: ERR=No such file or directory
ns1-fd JobId 9: Error: mkpath.c:140 Cannot create directory /var/opt/gitlab: ERR=No space left on device
```

Can someone help me and my configuration to do the work I want to expect?

Thank you very much!

At least another little question: Is it possible to also backup the OS (in my case Ubuntu Server 18.04.01 LTS) using bacula? But how would the restoring process look like?

Many thanks in advice!

Comment: This  question might be a better fit for ServerFault.com

Answer (score 0):

your error message says: "No space left on device", so you have to check free space on your filesystems. Did you run an accurate mode backup ([Accurate=Yes](https://www.bacula.org/9.4.x-manuals/en/main/Configuring_Director.html#SECTION002030000000000000000))?

Comment: Yes that's right I will check that! Is it possible to use Bacula for a complete disaster recovery?

Comment: I think yes, especially if you use Bacula Enterprise Bare Metal Recovery for Linux.